# Add a loop that allows me to display error statement and return to a certain place in the code

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a code that calculates batting average. I've got a couple of kinks right now. First, I'm trying to add an error message which would end progress and redirect the user to a previous point if they enter a foul string. I'm wanting this to happen where the program states "'Acceptable batting record codes are....'". How can I make the program request the players batting record again, and continue the code from there rather than continuing?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Prototype to keep console from closing.
class KeepRunning {
  public:
    ~KeepRunning() {
      system("pause");}};

//Define batting values
#define H  1
#define h  1
#define O  1
#define o  1
#define W  0
#define w  0
#define S  0
#define s  0
#define P  0
#define p  0

int main ()
{
KeepRunning kr;

int player;                 //Assign player number
double sum;                 //Assign variable for sum of H, h and O, o
double sumHits;             //Assign variable for sum of only H and h
double average;             //Assign variable for average of H and O
char size[100];             //Allows compiler to view user input as array
int b;                      //Assign variable for integer size
int letters = 0;            //Assing value of 0 to allow compiler to count

cout << "\t\t\tBatting Average Calculator\t\t";

cout << "\n\nEnter the player's number: ";
cin >> player;

cout << "Enter the player's batting record: ";
cin >> size;
    {b = 0;
     while (size[b] != 0)
     if (( size[b] = 'h','o','w','s','p') || (size[b] = 'H','O','W','S','P'))
     { letters++; b++; }
     else ( size[b] != 'h','o','w','s','p') || (size[b] != 'H','O','W','S','P');
     {cout << "\nAcceptable batting record codes are: 'H','O','W','S','P'. Please try again.\n";}}

//Summate H, h, O, o
sum = letters;

//Summate 
sumHits = H + h;

//Calculate batting average
average = sumHits/sum;

cout << "\nPlayer " << player << "'s batting record: " << size << endl;
cout << "Player " << player << "'s batting average: " << average << endl;

std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );         
return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code is not readable at all. Re-post it. Most likely what you need there is a "continue", so it will continue the loop, rather than exit it.

Comment: what's this about "keep console from closing". run your program from a command interpreter, or use Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio, or the appropriate keypress combo in some other IDE.

Comment: Your code contains synthax that don't belong in C++ at all.

Comment: Really? Is it all jamb\bled from your end? It looks correct on my computer, so I'm not sure how to fix it :/. It's not exiting, it's just going on. For example, I have step 1, then step 2. I have an if else statement after step 2. The else statement is where I have the error message, and I would want the program to start back at step 1 after the error. Not sure if you can answer a question based on that info, though :/

Comment: regarding `(size[b] = 'h','o','w','s','p')`, do read up on **assignment operator** and **comma operator**. this is not a comparison, and it's not a set expression.

Comment: Thanks Alf, I think that might be the problem area...

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 if (( size[b] = 'h','o','w','s','p') || (size[b] = 'H','O','W','S','P'))
 { letters++; b++; }
 else ( size[b] != 'h','o','w','s','p') || (size[b] != 'H','O','W','S','P');
 {cout << "\nAcceptable batting record codes are: 'H','O','W','S','P'. Please try again.\n";}}
```

This is not C++. You cannot compare `size[b]` with a group of elements like that, besides `=` is an assignment operator, as when you are assigning a value to the variable. If you were to compare both, you should use `==`.

In `else` you don't include new conditions. It works as *if [condition] do { this }, or **else** do { something else }*. If you ever need to be further specific in conditions use `else if`.

There are many ways to achieve what you seem to want here. You can compare `size[b]` with each element you want, for instance:

```
if ((size[b] == 'H') || (size[b] == 'h')
 || (size[b] == 'O') || (size[b] == 'o')
 || (size[b] == 'W') || (size[b] == 'w')
 || (size[b] == 'S') || (size[b] == 's')
 || (size[b] == 'P') || (size[b] == 'p')) {
    letters++; b++;
} else {
    cout << "\nAcceptable batting record codes are: 'H','O','W','S','P'. Please try again.\n";
}
```

Or with `switch` for clearer looks:

```
switch (std::tolower(size[b]))
{
    case 'h':
    case 'o':
    case 'w':
    case 's':
    case 'p':
        letters++;
        b++;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "\nAcceptable batting record codes are: 'H','O','W','S','P'. Please try again.\n";
}
```

Or even with a `std::set` of valid elements:

```
// at some part of program beginning
const char _dictionary[] = { 'h', 'o', 'w', 's', 'p' };
const std::set<char> dictionary(_dictionary, _dictionary + 5);

if (dictionary.find(std::tolower(size[b])) != dictionary.end()) {
    letters++;
    b++;
}
else {
    cout << "\nAcceptable batting record codes are: 'H','O','W','S','P'. Please try again.\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Havenard! That is extremely helpful. I'm thankful for everyone's critiques, but when you are new and learning something, a simple critique doesn't mean much without a definition. Thanks again!